# Delayed html updates in meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a list of players, each of which has a status. We order the players by status as well as showing the status via an icon like so:

[image]

I need to make it so when you click on a player, they change status icon immediately, but the order doesn't change until after a delay (for UX reasons). Any thoughts on the best way to do this.

Here's some ideas that won't work:

1. Changing `player.status` right away (the order changes under you).
2. Delaying changing `player.status` with a timeout (the icons won't change immediately, feels like nothing's happened).
3. Doing #2 and changing the icon class via jQuery: if you do a couple of changes the delayed update will do a redraw and you'll lose the class you set.

The best idea I have (and I'm aware it's pretty crappy) is:

4. Doing #2 but using a session variable per-player (`Session.get("player-$ID-status")`) to store the up-to-date version of the status.

There'll be some annoying plumbing to make this work, but I think it will. I'd love to hear a better way (or the 'meteor' way) to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there are a couple of more subtle ways to accomplish what you need. One way causes some coupling between user behavior and the changing state. The second way is a more decoupled and graceful approach, that would be more in line with the *meteor way*.

**First, the somewhat tightly coupled approach:**

You know that in your use case a player *should* change to a new status when the user indicates that they want the change to occur. I think the key here is that there's an interstitial state where a player *will change* to a state.

Given this breakdown, you may model this behavior with two attributes:

`player.status` and `player.statusWillBe`

If you implement it in this way, you may then base the icon off `player.changingToStatus`, and the ordering off `player.status`.

This means that all players will start off with the same value for `player.status` and `player.statusWillBe` - and in turn the icons will be set correctly based on the value in `player.statusWillBe`.

With this sort of breakdown, you have very fine grained control of the behavior based on user interaction, but your ui responses are tightly coupled to user behavior and non-ui components. That can get ugly quickly, if you continue to use this approach. You would basically be mixing model/state with ui.

**The more intricate decoupled approach (and in line with the *meteor way*):**

Implement a state machine for player state changes. You may then catch the state changes at the level of the change. Upon the state change you would [invalidate a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260439/meteor-deps-running-a-client-side-func) that causes your ui to redraw. This sort of approach is much cleaner, because it would completely decouple your ui from your "model". Meteor contexts and their invalidation are the key to client-side ui redraws, based on changes in the underlying model, without tightly coupling the two.

I would also highly suggest the following screencast to help you better understand this pattern: [Meteor reactivity with contexts.](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-reactivity-with-contexts)

Comment: Great answer, thanks @zealoushacker! I definitely agree with you; I like the second approach and I think it encapsulates a `ViewModel` pattern which I think in general is a really good idea. I've been thinking about such approaches for a little while now. Cheers.