# Meteor Deps - Running a Client Side Func

Tags: meteor

I'm struggling to get a handle on Meteor deps, in order to be specific my use case is:

2) When collection is changed, I want to run a jQuery function on the client side

I *think* deps are what I'm looking for, but at the moment I have only just used:

```
Template.templateName.set () ->
 return Set.find({})
```

...in terms of reactivity.

A solution which simply console.log's the collection each time it is changed would be more that enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do what you want using contexts. It's a little more complicated than it could be[1], but you can do what you want pretty easy if you follow the deps example from the docs. Something like

```
var setup = function() {
  var context = new Meteor.deps.Context();
  context.on_invalidate(function() {
    setup();
  });
  context.run(function() {
    Set.find({});
    console.log('changed');        
  });
}
setup();
```

Or you could make a helper that returns nothing to take advantage of the context that'll get setup for you:

```
Template.templateName.do_nothing -> 
  console.log 'changed'
  Set.find({})
  null
```

Although that will force the HTML to refresh when you might not want it to.

On the other hand, you might just want `Collection.observe`.

[1] If/when they merge this [pull request](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/193), you could just do something like:

```
Meteor.deps.await(function() { return Set.find(); }, function() { 
  console.log('changed'); 
});
```

You can take a look at the source of the `await` function if you want some more insight.

Comment: I didn't think of a template that returns null. I have it working, cheers. Quick Q though, is contexts actually the proper way to do something like this?

Comment: Yeah, I think contexts are exactly the right way to do it. Using a 'fake' helper feels like a hack to me. With the deps-extensions plugin it's markedly simpler to use contexts, and hopefully we can code reactively all over the place.